# Can't upload FBX in Mixamo after exporting FBX from Mixamo and editing the texture in Blender

Tags: texturing, export, import, mixamo

I downloaded an FBX file from Mixamo, edited the texture in Blender and want to re-upload it back to Mixamo, but I doesn't allow me to. It says "Unable to map your existing skeleton".

1. I read through all of the other similar posts with this topic, but I cannot export as an obj file, because I don't want to export my animations from blender (where I could add the textures later on). I want to re-upload to Mixamo to export as FBX for unity. To clarify: I want to download the animations from Mixamo because there is difference between exporting FBX from Blender and exporting FBX for unity from Mixamo.
2. I tried to make the file smaller, but it doesn't get significantly smaller even with the decimate property. I also don't think that this is the issue because the exported files from Mixamo can be re-uploaded and they huge.

If anyone figured out how to fix this please let me know, I would really appreciate it!
I have uploaded my FBX file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VhPeaYUrokz_j9XePFS0C69Szb0Ii0QO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "*but I doesn't allow me to*" Why, what happens? Do you get an error message, does it fail silently? Does it fail on import or export? Could you edit your question and clarify exactly what goes wrong?

Comment: To me, it's not clear why you want to re-upload the model to Mixamo. Is it just to download it as a FBX file? You know that you can export the model in Blender as FBX file directly, don't you?

Comment: @Blunder Ah yes I do, I want to download the animations from mixamo because there is difference between exporting fbx from blender and exporting fbx for unity from mixamo

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Ah thank you I will edit that. It says  "Unable to map your existing skeleton"

Comment: I'm not that familiar with uploading characters to Mixamo that have an existing rig. Maybe this video here helps: [How to Animate Your 3D Characters Fast by CG Boost](https://youtu.be/sTOgDe3EmQ0). He deletes here all non-deformation bones from the rig before he uploads the character to Mixamo and it seems to work with his own custom rig. After downloading from Mixamo again he can re-target the animation to the IK bones with bone constraints.

Comment: Thank you @Blunder for the suggestion, unfortunately that doesn't work for me because there aren't any non-deformation bones on the mixamo rig.

Comment: My question was thankfully answered right here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/mixamo-discussions/can-t-upload-fbx-in-mixamo-after-exporting-fbx-from-mixamo-and-editing-the-texture-in-blender/m-p/13852831#M2398